# Replace pressed key in TextBox to another C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How can I replace pressed 'decimal point' key from numpad to always return '.' independent of regional setting. I want that works only for one (specific) TextBox not all in application.

It's possible to accomplished this without creating own control?

Comment: Have you tried anything? An option would be to add a `KeyPressed` event to the `textbox`, where you check the Key that was pressed and in the case of the decimal point, you perform an action that adds the '.' character to the textbox instead of the ','.

Comment: what meaning of regional setting?

Comment: @BojanB I tried KeyDown, KeyUp, KeyPressed. For KeyDown, KeyUp you can't change character. In KeyPressed you can't determine character ',' went from numpad or alfakeys

Comment: @user6002727 in regional setting in Windows you can change decimal point character to dot or semicolon and dot key from numpad will return that character.

Comment: for what downvote question?

Comment: because you have not define every thing, and what you tried yet also not define,or may be your question is not fit to the stack overflow requirements and so on, one clarifcation is also that i doesn't down vote your question, I am also restricted to ask any question for 6 months.

Comment: @siwydym67 I have added a solution as an answer that should work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you simply need to handle the `KeyDown` event, supress the activated key if its the numpad decimal, and then simply send the new key you want.

It's pretty straightforward, the following links should give you enough pointers to actually write some code:

- [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`Control.KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Once you've written something, you can ask a new question about any specific dificulties you might encounter.

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution (most possibly not the best one, but one that should work) that would add a `.` character to a textbox if the decimal key on the numpad is pressed, if the `,` key is pressed it still adds the `,` character to the textbox.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
  {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true; 
    textBox1.Text += ".";
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
  }
}
```

The `SuppressKeyPress` prevents that the pressed key is sent to the textbox. Then you add the desired character to the textbox. The `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties are set to move the cursor to the end of the string in the textbox.

Hope that helps

**EDIT**:

As *cdkMoose* pointed out the flaw with this approach is that the `.`character is always added to the end of the string, if it is desired to add the `.`character anywhere in the string the code could be used like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal)
  {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    var caretPosition = textBox1.SelectionStart;  
    textBox1.Text.Insert(caretPosition , ".");
    textBox1.SelectionStart = caretPosition  + 1;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the caret position is not at the end of text.  I believe the desired result is to force a decimal regardless of the location in the textbox

Comment: @cdkMoose thanks for pointing that out, havent though about that, i modified the answer and now this case should also be covered

Comment: Change to `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(caretPosition, ".");`

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can handle `KeyDown` event and if is , on numpad cancel event and send new with '.'.